# What does "auth.User" in Django do?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to learn Django and I came across the following code in the books.

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
      )

    body = models.TextField() 

    def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

Even though I understand the most part of it I don't really understand what does `"auth.User"` do in the code. Furthermore, I tried searching for it in the documentation without any success (Which I found quite strange).

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'auth.user' is the model of the auth application which is part of Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/. In your code, you used the string 'auth.User' for ForeignKey. I modified the code a bit to explicitly import the User model from the auth application.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    body = models.TextField() 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

ForeignKey accepts string with class name of the model or model class itself. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.

Typically, string model names are used in the following cases:

1. > If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been
   >   defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model
   >   object itself
2. > Relationships defined this way on abstract models are resolved when
   >   the model is subclassed as a concrete model and are not relative to
   >   the abstract model’s app_label
3. > To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly
   >   specify a model with the full application label

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, strangely enough without importing the module it works great. How is that possible?

Comment: Using the string variant institutes a "lazy load" mechanism in Django, which can save you some headache in certain situations. I always use the string variant for this very reason (there's no real reason not to, as far as I know).

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

The `'auth.User'` specifier indicates what model the `ForeignKey` maps to. So, with the given model, each `Post` record will have a column named `author_id` (the `_id` suffix is automatically added by Django under the covers), and will point to an entry in the `User` table in the `auth` application (which is a built-in application).

See the [documentation on ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I’ve previously seen the link that you posted and didn’t find anything about auth.User any idea where I could find it and maybe even find the other models that ForeignKey can map to.